# Characterizations of regular holonomic D-modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, d-modules

I'm looking for references for the various characterizations of regular holonomic D-modules, in particular proofs of their equivalence. For instance, some characterizations I've seen (in the analytic category) are:

1. $\chi(M_x,\mathcal O_x) =\chi(M_x,\mathcal {\hat O}_x)$ for all $x$ [source for notation](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/D-module#Regular_holonomic_-modules.) (Though they give a source for this, I was unable to find it there)
2. $R\operatorname{Hom}_D(M_x, \mathcal O_x) \cong R\operatorname{Hom}_D(M_x,\hat {\mathcal O}_x)$ via the natural map for all $x$
3. A characterization having to do with V-filtrations near smooth points of subvarieties
4. The D-module inverse image along any morphism from a smooth curve is  regular in the sense of Fuchs

Comment: I think that the equivalence of 1,2, and 3, for D-modules on $\mathbb{A}^1$, is sketched in the first chapter of "D-modules coherents et holonomes" by Maisonobe and Sabbah.

Comment: Have you looked in Bjork's book? I think most of this stuff is there.

Comment: @SamGunningham Dang. It seems my library doesn't have Björk, and I can't afford my own copy at the moment. Well, I guess I'll be saving up my money. From what's available on Google books, it looks like what I'm looking for.

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) Interlibrary loan, or (2) ask the obvious person if you can borrow his copy.